# Laravel blade template showing html even when the condition is false

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have setup if conditions in my blade template with an if condition that consists of an or operator, but it is showing html even when the condition is false. Not sure how to fix that?

```
@if(count($images) || count($videos) > 1)
        <div class="orbit" role="region" data-orbit id="slider">
                <ul class="orbit-container">
                    <button class="orbit-previous"><span class="show-for-sr">Previous Slide</span>&#9664;&#xFE0E;</button>
                    <button class="orbit-next"><span class="show-for-sr">Next Slide</span>&#9654;&#xFE0E;</button>
            @if(count($images) > 1)
                    @foreach($images as $image)
                        <li class="orbit-slide">
                            <img src="http://coop.app/imagecache/cover/{{ $image }}" class="header-img">
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
            @endif
            @if(count($videos) > 1)
                    @foreach($videos as $video)
                            <li class="orbit-slide">
                                <div class="flex-video">
                                    <iframe src="{{ $video }}"></iframe>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                    @endforeach
            @endif
                </ul>
            </div>
        @endif
```

Comment: have to checked what `$images` and `$videos` is returning ? Please update your question with that value also.

Comment: are you sure that the whole condition is false? did you really want to check if `count(images)` is trueish (everything equal or greater than 1) or `count($videos)` is at least 2?

Comment: You need at least one image, or two videos?

Answer (score 0):

You write or (||) condition in if statement that means if one condition (count($images)) or count($videos)  is true then if statement will work.
If two condition is false then your if statement will not work

Answer (score 0):

I think your first condition is not correct : `@if(count($images) || count($videos) > 1)`. The `> 1` is not applied on both elements, you should try `@if(count($images) > 1 || count($videos) > 1)`.